# Is this a good method for filtering retweets from a search?

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I'm very new to twython (and not usually much of a tweeter, either).

I'm trying to return a search with no retweeted tweets in it (only originals). I've looked around a fair bit but answers are hard to come by on this.

So I noticed that each retweeted status has an object 'retweeted_status' which doesn't exist for original tweets.

I'm therefore filtering using something like this:

```
a_retweet = twitter.show_status(id=702944259981365249)
an_original_tweet = twitter.show_status(id=702937516098375681)

try:
    if an_original_tweet['retweeted_status']:
        print("FAIL")
except KeyError:
    print("KeyError: Tweet is original")
```

Now - it seems to work nicely ("FAIL" doesn't print), but to a more experienced python programmer, is the code any good?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be more appropriate for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `in` operator to check whether a dictionary contains a key:

```
if 'retweeted_status' in an_original_tweet:
    print('FAIL')
else:
    print('Tweet is original')
```

Comment: I felt like a complete idiot when I figured that one out - luckily I did so before coming back here!

Thanks a lot :)